# Django 1.8 can't serve img static file

Tags: django, static

New problem: my Django app isn't able to show an image.

Using Ubuntu, tried Chrome and Firefox. Django 1.8 in a local server (so I run `./manage.py runserver`).

I have followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ quite carefully and read and searched more documentation on Google, but there isn't too much about 1.8 and this problem, so this is my last resource. Here are my files:

SETTINGS.PY:
...

```
STATIC_URL = '/home/user/Escritorio/des/proyect/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/Escritorio/des/proyect/static/media/'
```

URLS.PY:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import settings 
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    

    url(r'^root/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^index$', 'views.index.page',name='index'),
    
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

INDEX.PY:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def page(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

INDEX.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "media/media/escudo.jpg" %}" alt="img"/> 
    hello!
</body>
</html>
```

So I can't see the img :( Just the "alt". When I inspect the object with developer tool, the route to the image is correct, so is actually linking to '/home/user/Escritorio/des/proyect/static/media/escudo.jpg' which is correct: there is exactly where the img is, but can't see it on the internet navigator.

Comment: Have you done `./manage.py collectstatic`? You didn't mention...

Comment: Note that there _is no_ Django 1.8 yet, you're using the development trunk which will become 1.8 sometime around April 2015.

Comment: Actually i forgot doing that. I understood it was needed for production, and not for only testing.
I have done it, and nothing, still doesnt work.

I selected: 
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/Escritorio/des/proyect/static/'

Same as static_url: i hope is fine.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: What is your STATIC_URL? It should have a value like '/static/'. Also in your template the filename has "media/media/", it's hard to believe that that would end up as a single /media/ in the generated HTML.

Comment: You shouldn't point those roots at the actual locations of the files, they should point to a location that they will be collected to when `collectstatic` is run. For example: `/var/www/html/static/` and `/var/www/html/media/`

Comment: Wait...what's your static URL? Can you post your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL`?

Comment: Thanks you all.

I have changed this:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/html/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/static/'
And did "collectstatic" then.

It doesnt work. Cant show the image

<img src="{% static "/media/erandom_pic.png" %}" alt="img"/> <hr>

Comment: SOLVED: In /var/www/html/media there was another media folder. Just copied the image up and it worked... thanks againg :)